# Custom payment method frontend requires JavaScript to be activated only after it is selected

Tags: payment, payment-methods, payment-gateway, extensions

### Background story

I am building a new payment method. I'm in the process of adding the `frontend` in the checkout page. The payment method require javascript.

So I have managed to add a script to the header of the checkout page.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <checkout_onepage_index>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs">
                <script>foo/bar.js</script>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_index>
</layout>
```

### The problem:

However in my case, `foo/bar.js` bind a DOM element which not yet exists. Hence error in the JavaScript. That DOM element is only added to the page after the buyers reach the payment stage.

One dirty solution is to addJs together with the content, such that the script is executed together. This method however give me a problem that the block [`checkout.payment.methods`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/cf43f51aab6125f03a0083df1c00ac0f34b86c86/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/checkout.xml#L336-L338) does not have the method `addJs`. If we're to use this approach, what should I do to be able to `addJs` in `checkout.payment.methods` block?

Alternatively, I keep the script at `head` block, and I update my JavaScript to be triggered only when the buyer select my payment method. However I am not sure what JavaScript event is being dispatch if we were to listen on payment method selected. What would it be?

Answer (score 1):

I cant be 100% sure because I dont know what the javascript what you want to add does. But I think the question here should be:

> Why you want to add javascript that instantly fires when its not
>   possible because elements are not there yet?

You have to build the JS in a manner that no errors occur when this happens.

And, to answer your question, fire the JS when the payment is selected. Just because it's probably irrelevant to the other payment options. So why would you run it?